# Dataframe is Being Returned as Empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and am trying to learn it to scrape data off of YouTube. I got this program from a very good YouTube tutorial video; it isn't showing any errors but is returning an empty dataframe for video_df. Looking for advice as to why this is happening and what I can do to correct this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Google API
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

api_key = '<api key>'
channel_ids = ['<channel_id>',
              ]

youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)


def get_channel_stats(youtube, channel_ids):
    """
    Get channel statistics: title, subscriber count, view count, video count, upload playlist
    Params:

    youtube: the build object from googleapiclient.discovery
    channels_ids: list of channel IDs

    Returns:
    Dataframe containing the channel statistics for all channels in the provided list: title, subscriber count, view count, video count, upload playlist

    """
    all_data = []
    request = youtube.channels().list(
        part='snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
        id=','.join(channel_ids))
    response = request.execute()

    for i in range(len(response['items'])):
        data = dict(channelName=response['items'][i]['snippet']['title'],
                    subscribers=response['items'][i]['statistics']['subscriberCount'],
                    views=response['items'][i]['statistics']['viewCount'],
                    totalVideos=response['items'][i]['statistics']['videoCount'],
                    playlistId=response['items'][i]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'])
        all_data.append(data)

    return pd.DataFrame(all_data)


def get_video_ids(youtube, playlist_id):
    """
    Get list of video IDs of all videos in the given playlist
    Params:

    youtube: the build object from googleapiclient.discovery
    playlist_id: playlist ID of the channel

    Returns:
    List of video IDs of all videos in the playlist

    """

    request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
        part='contentDetails',
        playlistId=playlist_id,
        maxResults=50)
    response = request.execute()

    video_ids = []

    for i in range(len(response['items'])):
        video_ids.append(response['items'][i]['contentDetails']['videoId'])

    next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')
    more_pages = True

    while more_pages:
        if next_page_token is None:
            more_pages = False
        else:
            request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
                part='contentDetails',
                playlistId=playlist_id,
                maxResults=50,
                pageToken=next_page_token)
            response = request.execute()

            for i in range(len(response['items'])):
                video_ids.append(response['items'][i]['contentDetails']['videoId'])

            next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')

    return video_ids


def get_video_details(youtube, video_ids):
    """
    Get video statistics of all videos with given IDs
    Params:

    youtube: the build object from googleapiclient.discovery
    video_ids: list of video IDs

    Returns:
    Dataframe with statistics of videos, i.e.:
        'channelTitle', 'title', 'description', 'tags', 'publishedAt'
        'viewCount', 'likeCount', 'favoriteCount', 'commentCount'
        'duration', 'definition', 'caption'
    """

    all_video_info = []

    for i in range(0, len(video_ids), 50):
        request = youtube.videos().list(
            part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
            id=','.join(video_ids[i:i + 50])
        )
        response = request.execute()

        for video in response['items']:
            stats_to_keep = {'snippet': ['channelTitle', 'title', 'description', 'tags', 'publishedAt'],
                             'statistics': ['viewCount', 'likeCount', 'favouriteCount', 'commentCount'],
                             'contentDetails': ['duration', 'definition', 'caption']
                             }
            video_info = {}
            video_info['video_id'] = video['id']

            for k in stats_to_keep.keys():
                for v in stats_to_keep[k]:
                    try:
                        video_info[v] = video[k][v]
                    except:
                        video_info[v] = None

            all_video_info.append(video_info)


def get_comments_in_videos(youtube, video_ids):
    """
    Get top level comments as text from all videos with given IDs (only the first 10 comments due to quote limit of Youtube API)
    Params:

    youtube: the build object from googleapiclient.discovery
    video_ids: list of video IDs

    Returns:
    Dataframe with video IDs and associated top level comment in text.

    """
    all_comments = []

    for video_id in video_ids:
        try:
            request = youtube.commentThreads().list(
                part="snippet,replies",
                videoId=video_id
            )
            response = request.execute()

            comments_in_video = [comment['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal'] for comment in
                                 response['items'][0:10]]
            comments_in_video_info = {'video_id': video_id, 'comments': comments_in_video}

            all_comments.append(comments_in_video_info)

        except:
            # When error occurs - most likely because comments are disabled on a video
            print('Could not get comments for video ' + video_id)

    return pd.DataFrame(all_comments)

channel_data = get_channel_stats(youtube, channel_ids)

# Convert count columns to numeric columns
numeric_cols = ['subscribers', 'views', 'totalVideos']
channel_data[numeric_cols] = channel_data[numeric_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

# Create a dataframe with video statistics and comments from all channels

video_df = pd.DataFrame()
comments_df = pd.DataFrame()

for c in channel_data['channelName'].unique():
    print("Getting video information from channel: " + c)
    playlist_id = channel_data.loc[channel_data['channelName'] == c, 'playlistId'].iloc[0]
    video_ids = get_video_ids(youtube, playlist_id)

    # get video data
    video_data = get_video_details(youtube, video_ids)
    # get comment data
    comments_data = get_comments_in_videos(youtube, video_ids)

    # append video data together and comment data toghether
    video_df = video_df.append(video_data, ignore_index=True)
    comments_df = comments_df.append(comments_data, ignore_index=True)

print(video_df)
```

Non-empty dataframe for video_df and data export to excel

Comment: You need to debug the code by looking what happens as it is executed not just at the end result. You could use print statements or the logging module or best an IDE with debugging in which you can step-through, set break points etc. VSCode works well with Jupyter Notebook and provides such facilities.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss a return statement in your function `get_video_details()`.

I guess you want to add `return pd.DataFrame(all_video_info)` to the end of the function.